# Magnus effect without windspeed

Tags: fluid-dynamics, aerodynamics, bernoulli-equation

Canagnus effect take place if windspeed is 0 ? Lets assume that our frame of reference a place an earth (e.g. soccer pitch) .We measure the windspeed and we find it zero.But if we make a knuckleshoot then how is it explained ? What produces the pressure difference in order for ball to change direcrion?

Answer (score 4):

The ball moves through the air, which results in a flow around the ball. From the viewpoint of the ball, that's a wind.

Comment: So we can only explain balls curve from ball reference frame?

Comment: Yes. Another example is wind tunnels where we let wind flow and keep models of what we want to study, e.g. cars or airplanes, still.